# "register in" or "register at"

Tags: prepositions

What preposition I should use after the verb "register" in this context:

> Students registered in/at the course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between the two, **in** makes much more sense than **at**.

**At** would only be used when discussing *where* you were when you registered:

> I registered for the course **at** the lecture hall.

But both **in** and **for** can be used immediately after *registered*, depending on if you are talking about the actual act of registration or the fact that a name is found in a list (a book or database).

> On the first day of school, I registered **for** a course.

Here, you are talking about the actual act of signing up for something.

But:

> On the first day of school, I registered ***myself*** **in** a course.

This implies that you are talking about having got your name entered into a course registration list.

The prepositions can normally be interchanged without the meaning being lost. (Although note that, for instance, the construction **registered myself** ***for*** **a course** sounds awkward.)

Other contexts also makes a difference.

Consider:

> Are you still registered **in** the course?
>   Are you still registered **for** the course?

In this case, the former sounds more natural because you're talking about if your name is still found in a list of registered students.

Meanwhile, the second sentence sounds strange because you think it should be rephrased as **Are you still** ***registering for*** **the course?** But that has a different meaning, and isn't what's intended if the registration process has been over for a while.

Answer (score 3):

You register FOR a course.

But if you mean where or how you do the registering, you might do it AT the university or ON a web site.